# Context not resolved inside a runnable thread

Tags: java, android

Here is the code inside main Activity class, which works fine..

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

mHandler = new Handler();
    context = this;
    ...
}
```

And the following code gives problem, don't know why:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
            mHandler = new Handler();
            context = this;
            ...
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: set ActivityClassName.this

Comment: you can make use of the AsyncTask if you want context in a Thread. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is similar to a Thread in Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
            mHandler = new Handler();
            context = this;
            ...
        }
    }).start();
```

In above code `.this` refers to `Thread (Runnable)` class object not a `Current Activity`. And you can not cast `Thread (Runnable) object` to `Android Context`.

or something like,

```
context = <MainActivity>.this
```

Comment: Because `getContentResolver()` is a Method of Activity or Context class. Use `mContext.getContentResolver()` or `<MainActivity>.this.getContentResolver()`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `context = this;` with `context = MainActivity.this` as it is referencing the `Thread` object not the `MainActivity` object.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the `Runnable` instance. You want the enclosing activity so use `MyActivityClass.this` instead.

Comment: Thanks Henry, One thing more after that i use "android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);" And here also "this.getContentResolver()" not resolved.. plz help..

Comment: Just leave out the `this` here: `android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);`